# How to fix Missing requirement for javax.imageio while building Eclipse-CDT using Maven?

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-3, eclipse-cdt

I downloaded the eclipse cdt source package org.eclipse.cdt-CDT_9_8_1.tar.xz from https://git.eclipse.org/c/cdt/org.eclipse.cdt.git and using maven 3.6.1 i tried to build it with command mvn clean install. Some packages were downloaded from repos and at the end it exited with the below error message

I need to build cdt from source as i want some changes in CDT source code. I am not an expert in Maven, not sure what's going wrong. Please help to resolve the issue

[INFO] Resolving dependencies of MavenProject: org.eclipse.cdt:org.eclipse.cdt.build.gcc.core:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT @ D:\Eclipse\Sources\CDT9.8.1_GIT\cdt-releng\org.eclipse.cdt\build\org.eclipse.cdt.build.gcc.core.polyglot.build.properties

[ERROR] Cannot resolve target definition:

[ERROR]   Software being installed: com.sun.xml.bind 2.2.0.v201505121915

[ERROR]   Missing requirement: com.sun.xml.bind 2.2.0.v201505121915 requires 'java.package; javax.imageio 0.0.0' but it could not be found

[ERROR] Failed to resolve target definition D:\Eclipse\Sources\CDT9.8.1_GIT\cdt-releng\org.eclipse.cdt\releng\org.eclipse.cdt.target\cdt.target: See log for details -> [Help 1]

[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.

[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:

[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MavenExecutionException

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is, that some plugins do not define a RequiredExecutionEnvironment. If such a plugin depends on a JRE package the build fails with the given error.

In Tycho it is possible to define such an environment:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
    <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
    <version>${tycho.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <!-- needed as some plugins do not set a execution environment they would fail to get jre packages (eg. javax.imageio) -->
        <executionEnvironment>JavaSE-1.8</executionEnvironment>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```